# Angular $http.get request failing after Auth0 Login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing an Angular SPA application. The $http.get request as follow:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8888/Treatments.php")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.treatments = response.data.records;
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log("Error: " + response.status);
            });
```

Which in normal conditions work great. The problem then arises when I authenticate a user using the Auth0 service. After a successful login, the following error arises in console when any $http.get requests are made:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/Treatments.php. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Why would this be happening and how will I be able to correct this unexpected behavior?

Comment: You need to handle this on the php side

Comment: @Sajeetharan from what I have gathered thusfar, the PHP is working perfectly fine. It is something to do with preflight headers in the angular $http.get request itself that I need to try and configure correctly...

Comment: The error comes from CORS, you will need to explicitely allow Authorization header in your CORS config. Can you make sure CORS is enabled http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work. The problem was with allowing CORS. To allow such requests, I simply added the following line to my .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This resolved all the issues.